# Yii: resolve Path Alias with short notation from inside a widget

Tags: php, yii

How to resolve the real path from inside widget of Path Alias in Yii framework in a generic way. By generic way I mean that widget can be installed weather in web application's `components` folder or in a module's `components` folder without one tweaks its code.
For instance

```
Yii::getPathOfAlias('application.components.timepicker.assets');
```

works fine if I install my widget in web application's `components` folder, but if I put it in a certain module's `components` folder this won't work. Is there a way to skip `application.components` like:

```
Yii::getPathOfAlias('timepicker.assets');
```

with any reasonable additional modifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yii requires path aliases to be absolute, so you cant use `timepicker.assets`. Solution is to create your own path alias in main component class:

```
<?php
Yii::setPathOfAlias('timepicker', dirname(__FILE__)); 

class ETimepicker
{
    ....
```